# Firebase childEventListener onChildAdded adding duplicate objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listener for a logged in user's list of matches which looks like the following:

```
matchesListener = mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS)
    .child(currentUser.getId())
    .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES)
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

and the onChildAdded method looks like the following:

```
if(!acceptedMatches.contains(dataSnapshot.getValue(Match.class))){
    acceptedMatches.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Match.class));
    matchFragment.adapterMatches.notifyDataSetChanged();
}else{
    //Do nothing
}
```

this code adds the added value to the list and then notifies the adapter to update. A match can only be added to the user's match list once a pending request has been accepted by the target user. If a user accepts, the following code is run (by clicking on the accept button in the custom adapter I have created):

```
//remove from pending in currentUser
mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(mainScreen.currentUser.getId()).child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_PENDING).child(match.getMatchId()).removeValue();

//add current user to target user
mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(mainScreen.currentUser.getId()).child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES).child(match.getMatchId()).setValue(match);

//add target user to current user
mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(match.getMatchId()).child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES).child(mainScreen.currentUserMatch.getMatchId()).setValue(mainScreen.currentUserMatch);
```

The data is correctly added in firebase, however the ui is not updated correctly. Apparently, once the pending user has been accepted, that same user will show up in both match lists. So, both users will have the same match, where one user will have him/herself added to the match list. I figured that the onChildAdded method for the match listener is responsible for this, but I cannot seem to figure out why it would be causing this problem.

EDIT: It seems that the same dataSnapshot is being pulled when it shouldn't. The following line

```
//add target user to current user
        mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(match.getMatchId()).child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES).child(mainScreen.currentUser.getId()).setValue(mainScreen.currentUserMatch);
```

SHOULD be returning a different snapshot vs. when:

```
//add current user to target user
            mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(mainScreen.currentUser.getId()).child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES).child(match.getMatchId()).setValue(match);
```

is called. However, they're both returning the same snapshot which then causes the same user to be added to both the target and currently logged in user's ui (as i said before the data is correctly added in firebase; both users show up in each other's match lists).

Comment: It seems that this issue only presents itself when switching between users on the same device without stopping the app. If I accept a pending request and then force stop the app itself, then log in as the other user, it will show the correct match on the ui. I'm not sure whats causing this issue, as I am removing all listeners in onDestroy